# Shared data member of class among all instances of the class in the same thread

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, static, thread-safety

In my `C#` MVC project, I have a static member in a class which is updated by another instance of the same class. But the problem is that all threads which have an instance of this class is also using the same memory to update the static variable. But I don't want the variable shared across threads.

Is there any way by which I can make a data member of the class be shared among all the instances of the class in the same thread, but create a new memory location if in a different thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may or may not suit your needs, but one way you could potentially solve this is to use a *Thread Static Field*

[ThreadStaticAttribute Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threadstaticattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Indicates that the value of a static field is unique for each thread.
>
> A static field marked with ThreadStaticAttribute is not shared between
>   threads. Each executing thread has a separate instance of the field,
>   and independently sets and gets values for that field. If the field is
>   accessed on a different thread, it will contain a different value

**Note** that in addition to applying the `ThreadStaticAttribute` attribute to a field, you must also define it as a `static`

```
public class Example
{
   [ThreadStatic] static double previous = 0.0;
   [ThreadStatic] static double sum = 0.0;
   [ThreadStatic] static int calls = 0;
   [ThreadStatic] static bool abnormal;
   ...
```